# How to update record in R - problem with sqldf

Tags: sql, r, warnings, dbi

I would like to change some records in my table. I think the easest way is to use sqldf and Update. But when i using it i get warning (the table b isn't empty):

```
c<-sqldf("UPDATE b
          SET l_all = ''
          where id='12293' ")

# In result_fetch(res@ptr, n = n) :
# SQL statements must be issued with dbExecute() or dbSendStatement() instead of dbGetQuery() or dbSendQuery().
```

Can you help me how to change chosen records in the easest way?

Answer (score 0):

The query worked but there are several possible problems:

1. The message is a spurious warning, not an error, caused by backwardly incompatible changes to RSQLite.  You can ignore the warning or use the sqldf2 workaround here: https://github.com/ggrothendieck/sqldf/issues/40
2. The SQL update command does not return anything so one would not expect the command shown in the question to return anything.  To return the updated value ask for it.

**1)** Using the built in BOD data frame, defining sqldf2 from (1) and taking into account (2) we have:

```
sqldf2(c("update BOD set demand = 0 where Time = 1", "select * from BOD"))
```

giving:

```
  Time demand
1    1    0.0
2    2   10.3
3    3   19.0
4    4   16.0
5    5   15.6
6    7   19.8
```

**2)** Another approach to do it is to use select giving the same result.

```
sqldf("select Time, iif(Time == 1, 0, demand) demand from BOD")
```

Comment: Thank you. Second example works, but it add a new column at the end of the table and leave previous column. I need to update existed column. 

I try to install sqldf2 but I get information about wrong version of R (information is in the next post, because text is too long)

Comment: (2) does NOT add a new column. It overwrites the demand column. sqldf2 is just 5 lines of R code that you copy and paste into your session. There is no package to install.  Please read the link carefully again.

Comment: In (2) I use "Select *", because I have many other columns and after that column demand is duplicated. In (1) when I use function from link everythink in console is in blue and i also can't do anything also "view" don't work. Now I use this in R: "BOD$demand[BOD$TIME=="1"]=NA".  It works.

Now I need to replace this "1" to NULL. When I use NA then I got NA in text. Do you know how to fix this issue?

Comment: Obviously if you list it twice it will come out twice.  I can't reproduce any problems using sqldf2.  Anyways you can just use sqldf and ignore any warnings.  If we set `BOD$demand[1] <- NA` then `sqldf2(c("update BOD set demand = 0 where demand is null", "select * from BOD"))` will output BOD with the NA replaced with 0.